# Bash: get current working directory name, but not full path

Tags: command-line, bash

I know that `pwd` will  print the full path of current working directory, but I want to print only the name of the directory. Is there a simple command to do this without to parse `pwd`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use pure bash:

```
echo "${PWD##*/}"
```

or better, to avoid the case when you could be in `-e` directory:

```
printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}"
```

(thanks to @gniourf_gniourf for the second suggestion).

Or you can use `basename` tool:

```
basename "$PWD"
```

Comment: Also `basename ~+`

Comment: you can also do ```echo "${PWD##*/}"```

Comment: 1. what is -e directory 2. "${PWD##*/}" how does this work?

Comment: I prefer `basename \`pwd\``