# Zenity: get selected filename without its path

Tags: command-line, zenity

I need `zenity` to put a selected filename into a variable without its path.
What I have now is

```bsh
file_to_copy="$(zenity --file-selection --title='Select a File')"
echo $file_to_copy
```

then prints

```
/home/blades/Scripts/openwrt-vpn-renew/ze.sh
```

I wanted to just print `ze.sh`.

Comment: Do you really need `zenity` to provide this natively? can you not just use `"${file_to_copy##*/}"` (or use the `basename` command)?

Comment: steeldriver yes that's it. "${file_to_copy##*/}" Thanx so much.

Comment: @steeldriver I wanted to close this as a duplicate but it is over on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash. Could you post an answer here that can be accepted? (Ping me and I'll up-vote :))

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix done - please see below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: get current working directory name, but not full path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375395/bash-get-current-working-directory-name-but-not-full-path)

Comment: Also on Superuser: https://superuser.com/q/443859/418028

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't absolutely need `zenity` to provide this functionality for you, then you can easily do it in the shell, either using [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
file_to_copy=${file_to_copy##*/}
```

where `##*/` refers to the longest leading string matching `*/`, or using the `basename` utility

```
file_to_copy=$(basename "$file_to_copy")
```